# POS (Point of Sale) Printer integration in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, posprinter

I have an angular app developed in angular version 8. I need to integrate EPSON TM-T82. pos thermal printer for printing purpose. I searched for packages in npm and doesn't anyone. Is any npm integration available for that? I tried the Javascript SDK provided by EPSON, but it communicates only with an intelligent printer ie TM-T82i versions.

In a web application I want to print a receipt using a POS (Point of Sale) Printer. I want to do that with angular. Can anyone provide me an example for that?

Comment: `Javascript SDK` you need to check with vendor, if it's not there you can create using `net` module of Node.js. which communicate over `TCP/IP` protocol.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectlistener

Comment: You can establish connection with online printer using above `Node.js Net module`.

Comment: In browser, TCP socket api is in experimental phase.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/TCPSocket

Comment: Can be created using the npm package manager